# Resharper, linq within foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, resharper

Resharper is suggesting to use the top example, over the bottom example. However I am under the impression that a new list of items will be created first, and thus all of the _executeFuncs will be run before the runstoredprocedure is called.

This would normally not be an issue, however exceptions are prone to occur and if my hypothesis is correct then my database will not be update despite the functions having been ran??

```
foreach (var result in rows.Select(row => _executeFunc(row)))
   {                   
      RunStoredProcedure(result)
   }
```

Or

```
 foreach(var row in rows)
   {
       var result = _executeFunc(row);
       RunStoredProcedure(result);
   }
```

Comment: You mean exceptions can happen within `_executeFunc`?

Comment: Read about deferred execution.

Comment: apologies, yes the executeFunc(row) is prone to throw errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statements are, in this case, semantically the same as `Select` (and linq in general) uses deferred execution of delegates. It won't run any declared queries until the result is being materialised, and depending on how you write that query it will do it in proper sequence.

A very simple example to show that:

```
var list = new List<string>{"hello", "world", "example"};

Func<string, string> func = (s) => {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    return s.ToUpper();
};

foreach(var item in list.Select(i => func(i)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

results in

```
hello
HELLO
world
WORLD
example
EXAMPLE
```

Answer (score 4):

In your first example, `_executeFunc(row)` will NOT be called first for each item in `rows` before your `foreach` loop begins.  LINQ will defer execution.  See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946207/does-foreach-cause-repeated-linq-execution) for more details.

The order of events will be:

1. Evaluate the first item in `rows`
2. Call `executeFunc(row)` on that item
3. Call `RunStoredProcedure(result)`
4. Repeat with the next item in `rows`

Now, if your code were something like this:

```
foreach (var result in rows.Select(row => _executeFunc(row)).ToList())
{                   
   RunStoredProcedure(result)
}
```

Then it WOULD run the LINQ `.Select` first for every item in `rows` because the `.ToList()` causes the collection to be enumerated.

Comment: Thanks guys both really good answers, wish I could pick both as the correct answers. I chose J. Steen's as it provided an output example sorry

Comment: No problem, glad you found your answer!

Answer (score 3):

In the top example, using [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) will project the rows, by `yielding` them one by one.

So

`foreach (var result in rows.Select(row => _executeFunc(row)))`

is basically the same as

`foreach(var row in rows)`

Thus Select is doing something like this

```
for each row in source
   result = _executeFunc(row)
   yield result
```

That yield is passing each row back one by one (it's a bit more complicated than that, but this explanation should suffice for now).

If you did this instead

`foreach (var result in rows.Select(row => _executeFunc(row)).ToList())`

Calling [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) will return a List of rows immediately, and that means _executeFunc() will indeed be called for every row, before you've had a chance to call `RunStoredProcedure()`.

Thus what Resharper is suggesting is valid. To be fair, I'm sure the Jetbrains devs know what they are doing :)

Answer (score 2):

`Select` uses deferred execution. This means that it will, in order:

- take an item from `rows`
- call `_executeFunc` on it
- call `RunStoredProcedure` on the result of `_executeFunc`

And then it will do the same for the next item, until all the list has been processed.

Answer (score 1):

The execution will be deferred meaning they will have the same exec