# When do LINQ Lambdas execute in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So, to keep it short, I have this bit of code in which I loop through the results of a string split and add them to a list, if they have not occurred before in the loop. This is the code.

```
var res = new List<string>();
foreach(string s in input.Split(new[] { ", " }, 
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    if(res.All(p => p != s))
        res.Add(s);
}
```

But after I wrote this code, Visual Studio said I could convert part of the loop into LINQ. However, I'm a bit skeptical about whether this'll work or not.

Basically, my question is, would the lambda expressions be executed on each separate loop, or just once in the beginning?

```
var res = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in input.Split(new[] { ", " }, 
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          .Where(s => res.All(p => p != s)))
{
    res.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does "foreach" cause repeated Linq execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946207/does-foreach-cause-repeated-linq-execution)

Comment: `foreach` will enumerate the IEnumerable that results after evaluation of the entire statement. The entire LINQ statement is evaluated before `foreach` even starts

Comment: just once in the beginning

Comment: @AlekDepler actually, before the loop even starts. `foreach` will execute *after* the call to `Where` returns the final IEnumerable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the example of working lazy evaluation of `Linq` queries.

```
List<int> vals = new List<int> {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4};
var res = new List<int>();
foreach (int s in vals.Where(s => 
                       { 
                           Console.WriteLine("lambda"); 
                           return s % 2 == 0; 
                       }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("loop");
}
```

And the output will be

```
lambda
lambda
lambda
loop
lambda
loop
lambda
lambda
loop
```

As you can see lambda will be evaluated only when the next element is required by `foreach` loop

Comment: This is a nice example and actually answers the question.

Comment: Actually, I find it doesn't explicitly answer the question *"Would the lambda expressions be executed on each separate loop, or just once in the beginning?"* because Dmitry says it will be evaluated *"only when the next element is required"* - this means that actually the lambda **is** evaluated *on each separate loop*.
I would suggest changing the wording of the answer to reflect this fact better.

Answer (score 7):

Basically you are just trying to get the distinct values:

```
var res = input.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();
```

Comment: While this is a better alternative it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @juharr yet this answer belongs here just to show how good code can fix problems like "I don't know how this code works"

Answer (score 1):

I built on [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822373/2822719) and made output a little more verbose to show you what is really going on. Also note, that as [Ufuk noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822197/2822719), there a better ways to achieve a list of distinct values.

Feel free to test this for your own and play around with it a little in this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/892EyJ).

**Here is the example:**

```
List<int> input = new List<int> {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4};
var res = new List<int>();
foreach (int s in input.Where(s => 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("lambda: s=" + s);
        Console.WriteLine("lambda: " + s + " contained in res? " + res.Contains(s));
        return !res.Contains(s);
    }))
{
    res.Add(s);
    Console.WriteLine("loop: " + s + " added to res");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**It produces the following output:**

```
lambda: s=1
lambda: 1 contained in res? False
loop: 1 added to res

lambda: s=1
lambda: 1 contained in res? True
lambda: s=2
lambda: 2 contained in res? False
loop: 2 added to res

lambda: s=2
lambda: 2 contained in res? True
lambda: s=3
lambda: 3 contained in res? False
loop: 3 added to res

lambda: s=4
lambda: 4 contained in res? False
loop: 4 added to res
```